# How to wait for two different publishers to finish and return value from one of them in reactor application

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a flux which is from a sink.

```java
Scheduler s = Schedulers.parallel();
Long[] data = new Long[10]{10, 20,...};

Sinks.Many<Long> dataSink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
var flux = dataSink.asFlux().publishOn(s).doOnNext(d -> log.info("got {}", d));

var mono = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
  val map = new HashSet<Long>();
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Long datum = data[i];
    map.add(datum);
    log.info("sending....{}", i);
    dataSink.tryEmitNext(datum);
  }
  return map;
});
```

How to wait for both flux and mono, and then return the value from mono. Note that the flux depends on the mono since the sink is emitting inside the supplier of the mono.

One option is:

```java
Mono.when(flux, mono).block();
return mono.block();
```

But I dont want to block as I will have to return the mono from the function which will be later subscribed by the client. Another option is to use Flux.merge, but that returns a serializable and I dont know how to get back the value from mono.

Comment: Here the flux is not doing anything but say, flux after receiving from the sink does some processing which can take time (5ms for example)

Comment: How about `Mono.or()` instead? See its JavaDocs: `Emit the first available signal from this mono or the other mono.`

Comment: since the mono (mainWork) supplier emits to the flux. Doing the mono.or will immediately get the value from flux and subscription stops. I need something which egarly subscribes to both flux and mono, waits for them to complete and then allows me to get the value from mono.

Comment: `Mono.zipWith(Mono)` then? In the result `Tuple2` you'll have both values from both your monos.

Comment: zipWith does work but looks like it emits everything then flux is processing it which means everythings is getting bufferred  which is not good. I experimented and found that: Mono.zip(flux.then(Mono.just(1)), mainWork).block() is working. we need to do this workaround to convert the flux to mono. As I dont care about the output of flux, i did a dummy mono. This way, the flux is subscribed immediately and it starts consuming as soon as the mono (mainWork) emits. This is good. thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what data you need from `Flux` and how do you want to resolve them (sequentially or in parallel).

For sequential processing you can use

```
flux.then(mono)
```

To resolve in parallel, you can convert `Flux` to `Mono` and then use `Mono.zip`

```
Mono.zip(flux.last(), mono)
```